# Arduino: Software Disabling Reset not working?

Tags: arduino

Thanks to the answer below, I've began implementing solutions found on http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection

The hardware solution seems to work, but it's VERY troublesome because it requires you to have the capacitor on AFTER you upload your code.

I've tried experimenting with the perl and python scripts provided:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600, timeout=1)
ser.dsrdtr = False
ser.setDTR(level=False)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Device::SerialPort;


my $port = Device::SerialPort->new("/dev/ttyACM0");
$port->databits(8);
$port->baudrate(9600);
$port->parity("none");
$port->stopbits(1);
$port->dtr_active(0);

sleep(1);
```

I ran these scripts after my arduino has started and none of them work. Can someone explain why? (I've double checked to ensure it's /dev/ttyACM0 and 9600 baud rate)

**Btw, I am on arduino mega**

Answer (score 0):

You can apparently do this either through hardware (temporarily or permanently) or through software as discussed [here](http://wp.yellowkazoo.com/?p=177) and [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection)

Comment: So...try the hardware solution ;-)